# if mouseleave/ if click in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way in javascript to define what happens depending on if you just hover over an element or if you actually click it?

What I want to do is, for a button:

- onmouseenter, the background-color is supposed to change.
- If you just  hover over it and leave the button again, the color is supposed to disappear.
- If you click it, the color is supposed to "stay".

Is there a way to do this along the lines of `if mouseout == true/ if click == true?`

I tried looking it up but nothing really answered my question. Thank you very much in advance!

Edit: I definitely want to do it in Javascript, I'm aware of the fact that it can be easily done in CSS
Edit 2: This is what I tried:

```
var ifclick = false;
element.onclick = function() {
    element.style.background = "pink";
    element.style.borderColor = "pink";
    ifclick = true;
};

if (ifclick == false) {
    element.onmouseout = function() {
        element.style.background = "white";
        element.style.borderColor = "white";
    };
}
else {
    element.style.background = "pink";
    element.style.borderColor = "pink";
};
```

element is the button whichever your mouse enters, ifclick is supposed to return "true" when the button is clicked, this the element.onmouseout function is ONLY supposed to if the button has not been clicked but for some reason (as stated below) the button is only pink as long as your mouse is still on the button and turns white as soon as you leave.

Comment: This doesn't need tricky JavaScript, only CSS. (And if the :focus pseudo class does not fully serve your requirements, then it at most needs JS to set an additional class "active" or sth like that on the button.)

Comment: What have you tried? We need sth to start with...

Comment: Yes there is a way to do this

Comment: What I first tried to create to functions. One being element.onmouseout = function () ... and then afterwards element.click = function () .... but that doesnt work (the color still disappears). Then I tried using an if/else statement along the lines of if (mouseout == true) { //some code}. Neither worked

Comment: Well then you will need to "remember" the fact that the button was clicked in some kind of state variable, so that next time the mouseout handler is called, it can check for that, and then decide _not_ to change the background color back ...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I tried setting a variable that changes when the element has been clicked and it "kinda" works, but the problem is, that it only changes the color WHILE I'm clicking it and the color gets removed afterwards

Comment: Edit your question, show what you tried.

Comment: @A.S.J Take a look at my answer. I addressed the issue

Comment: @JustinJmnz I'll try that out, thank you very much! (sorry for the late reply)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using jQuery. Consider my code bellow:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Button Test</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <button id="btn">Text</button>
 <script>
 var persistence = false;

 $( "#btn" ).mouseenter(function() {
  $( this ).css("background-color", "yellow");  
 });

 $( "#btn" ).click(function(event) {
  $( this ).css("background-color", "yellow");
  persistence = true;
 }); 

 $( "#btn" ).mouseleave(function(event) {
  if( persistence === false){
   $( this ).css("background-color", "inherit");
  }
 });
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Taken from [W3 School](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp) for mouse over.

```
<img onmouseover="bigImg(this)" src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley">
```

Also Taken from [W3 School](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events_examples.asp) for mouse click.

```
<body onmousedown="whichElement(event)">
```

**Update**

Based on what you said, you need a way of adding a `.class` when the mouse enters an area, and removing the `.class` when it leaves the area. Look into [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_events_onmouse).

```
<h1 onmouseover="style.color='red'" onmouseout="style.color='black'">Mouse over this text</h1>
```

Pure Javascript example,

```js
window.onload = function() {
 var htmlElement = document.getElementById("foo");
    var clicked = false;

    document.getElementById("foo").addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
        if(!clicked) {
            htmlElement.style.color = "red";
        }
    });
    document.getElementById("foo").addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
        if(!clicked) {
            htmlElement.style.color = "black";
        }
    });
    document.getElementById("foo").addEventListener("click", function(){
        htmlElement.style.color = "red";
        clicked = (clicked ? false : true);
    }); 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="foo">Hello!</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

There is similarly a wide variety of DOM Events you can catch (Like `onClick`). Find most of them [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp).